# Что значит запись ~Ɐx(D(x))?

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

Вот есть запись:  ~Ɐx(D(x))

~ - отрицание

D(x) - предикат,

Ɐ - для всех x.

а как читаеться эта запись? для всех x ложен предикат? или как, и как она будет работать на каком небудь примере?

Comment: Может, это то же, что и ∃x(~D(x))? :)

Comment: И, кстати, предиктор или предикат?...

Comment: @Harry да предикат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта запись читается "не для каждого x выполняется D(x)" или "не для каждого x истинно D(x)".

Например, если `D(x)` - это предикат "x - четное", то `~Ɐx D(x)` означает "не для каждого х истинно, что x - четное". Это дейтвительно эквивалентно "существует x такое, что х - нечетное".

Обратите внимание, что это не то же самое, что "для всех х ложен предикат D(x)". Это выражение записывается так `Ɐx ~D(x)`.